# Seaborn heat map with correlation to string

Tags: python, heatmap

I'm trying to build a heatmap to illustrate the correlation between indexes and a range (string).

```
data = {'Report': [1,2,3,4],
        'Hours': [30,45,85,24],
        'Wage': [100,446,245,632],
        'Worker': [321,63,456,234],
        'Buyer': [36,53,71,52],
        'Range': ['High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Low']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Report', 'Hours', 'Wage', 'Worker', 'Buyer', 'Range'])
```

My expected result would be a heatmap with 'Hours', 'Wage', 'Worker', and 'Buyer' on the left as indexes and three categories in 'Range' on the bottom.

How do I achieve the desired result using seaborn heatmap?
Thanks in advance!
I appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Report': [1,2,3,4],
    'Hours': [30,45,85,24],
    'Wage': [100,446,245,632],
    'Worker': [321,63,456,234],
    'Buyer': [36,53,71,52],
    'Range': ['High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Low']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Report', 'Hours', 'Wage', 'Worker', 'Buyer', 'Range'])
df_corr = df.corr()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9)) 
sns.heatmap(df_corr, square=True, vmax=1, vmin=-1, center=0)

print(df_corr)

          Report     Hours      Wage    Worker     Buyer
Report  1.000000  0.103434  0.774683  0.103496  0.595586
Hours   0.103434  1.000000 -0.333933  0.548300  0.845140
Wage    0.774683 -0.333933  1.000000 -0.542259  0.208270
Worker  0.103496  0.548300 -0.542259  1.000000  0.356177
Buyer   0.595586  0.845140  0.208270  0.356177  1.000000
```

Just calculate the correlation coefficients and draw them with a headmap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am looking for a heatmap that correlates 'Hours', 'Wage', 'Worker', and 'Buyer'  with 'Range'.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand the intent of the question.'